# Grabbing nested variable depending on object name

Tags: java

I have an object formatted like so

```java
public static class ActionTypes {
  private Punch punch;
  private Kick kick;

  public static class Punch {
    private Integer force;
  }
  public static class Kick {
    private Integer force;
  }
}
```

and given a String parameter like `punch` or `kick`, I want to grab its corresponding `force`. What's the best way to implement this?

Comment: Hard to determine "best". But one way to to have them derive from a common ancestor that has a `force` member.

Comment: Also a common ancestor with a `getForce()` method.  Prob don't want to be accessing fields directly.

Comment: If it is as simple as your example, go for `switch`. Otherwise have a look at Reflection.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
public static class ActionTypes {
    private final Map<String, Force> map = new HashMap<>();
    
    public void setPunch(Punch punch) {
        map.put("punch", punch)
    }
    
    public void setKick(Kick kick) {
        map.put("kick", kick);
    }
    
    public Force getForce(String id) {
        return map.get(id.toLowerCase());
    }
  
    public static interface Force {
        Integer getForce();
    }       

    public static class Punch implements Punch {
        private Integer force;
        
        public Integer getForce() {
            return force;
        }
    }
    
    public static class Kick implements Punch {
        private Integer force;
        
        public Integer getForce() {
            return force;
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need public getters at each level if appropriate, assuming your language is Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `enum` class in java,

```
enum actionType {
    PUNCH("punch", 10),
    KICK("kick", 20);

    private String action;
    private int force;

    actionType(String action, int force) {

        this.action = action;
        this.force = force;
    }

    public String getAction() {

        return action;
    }

    public int getForce() {

        return force;
    }
}
```

and according to the string value you can get the force like this,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "punch";
    if(actionType.PUNCH.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
        System.out.println(actionType.PUNCH.getForce());
    }
}
```